# Is the uint "ID" in this function saved in storage?

Tags: storage

I am a bit confused about the uint "id" in the start function.

I understand that the uint "nextCampaignId" is a global variable, and so changes made to it will be saved in storage; which means that with each new campaign created, "nextCampaignId" will be incremented, and so cannot be used to determine ID numbers of previously created campaigns.  Hence, we need to assign its value to a new uint "id" within the function.

However, I thought integers declared within functions do not get saved in storage.  Wouldn't this ID number be lost once the function is terminated?  Does the function simply return the ID (to the UI) and then forgets it? But then how can we retrieve specific campaign data later?

```
uint nextCampaignId;
mapping(uint256 => CampaignData) campaigns;

// Start a new campaign.
function start(address recipient, uint256 goal, uint256 deadline) returns 
(uint id) {
    var campaign = campaigns[nextCampaignId];
    campaign.recipient = recipient;
    campaign.goal = goal;
    campaign.deadline = deadline;
    nextCampaignId ++;
    id = nextCampaignId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything you say is true, but `nextCampaignId` *isn't* declared inside the function. It's just *used* inside the function.

If it was declared there, the function would look something like this:

```
function start(address recipient, uint256 goal, uint256 deadline) returns 
(uint id) {
    var campaign = campaigns[nextCampaignId];
    campaign.recipient = recipient;
    campaign.goal = goal;
    campaign.deadline = deadline;
    uint nextCampaignId;
    nextCampaignId ++;
    id = nextCampaignId;
}
```

Also, the reason why `id = nextCampaignId;` is needed is just because the function header says that the variable `id` should be returned. Nothing else. It could also be a simple `return nextCampaignId;`.

Comment: The directl answer to your question is the last part. id = xxxx is simply setting the return value. It could have been written as `return nextCampignId`;

Comment: I know "nextCampaignId" is declared outside of the function (I was referring to "uint ID" within the funtion).  But then it will be changed with each new campaign.  So, for example, the second campaign will change this to 2, but then wouldn't the ID "1" for the first campaign be lost?

Comment: What do you mean by "lost"? Whoever calls `start()` can simply save the id if he's going to need it again. In the contract it's implicitly stored since it's the index in the `campaigns` array.

Comment: I would think that the function would increment the global variable nextCampaignId each time it is used and so returning this would only bring back the latest number.

Comment: Yes, and the latest number is the id of the new campaign, which is exactly what you would expect the function `start()` to return. When you (as a user) call `start()` you get back the id of the campaign you created. You can then store that somewhere or just remember it. When you want to do something to the campaign, you send that id to the contract and the contract can then lookup the id in the `campaigns` array to retrieve your campaign.

Comment: Does this mean that mappings save the current number to storage each time the function is run? - for each new campaign? - but that users can only input them to look up campaigns but cannot look up what the numbers are later?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much spot on. Two minor corrections though: 1. everything that happened on the blockchain can later be looked up again. That includes the generated campaign id. The transaction that generated it will always stay in the blockchain and so will all the data it generated. 2. you can iterate over all campaigns in the array and *search* for your campaign. That's not very efficient though and not really useful.

Comment: Okay, I think I over-looked some basics.  I should have enough to chew on here.  Thanks all!